# Java for smslib: building error for sending message using smslib

Tags: java, smslib

i installed lib smslib for my project for sending message example in the lib smslib-v3.5.3.
i followed all the instructions at the website smslib.org for lib setup.
But i found the error.

```
 public class SendMessage{
public void doIt() throws Exception
{
    OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
    System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
    System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com9", "COM9",                 9600, "InterCEL", "");
    gateway.setInbound(true);
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
    gateway.setSimPin("0000");
    gateway.setSmscNumber("+84920210006");
    Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
    Service.getInstance().startService();;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Modem Information:");
    System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
    System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
    System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
    System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
    System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
    System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
    System.out.println();
    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("0987623500", "Hello");
    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
    System.in.read();
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
{
    public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
    {
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
    try
    {
        app.doIt();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by org.smslib
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:102)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

please help me a little.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It has been years since last time I used JavaCOM but here is ListPorts test app. See if you can see any devices in virtual com ports. My SMS send+receive applications used smslib-3.4.0.jar release with rxtx libraries.

I always used RXTX .jar+.dll/.so files in Linux and Windows. Found some devices+OSses did not work properly with JavaCOM standard dll library.
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

**Files to be used**
ListPorts.bat
lib/myapp.jar  (or use ./classes classpath)
lib/librxtxSerial.so
lib/logging.properties
lib/RXTXcomm.jar
lib/rxtxSerial.dll  (32bit, never used 64bit lib)

**lib/logging.properties**

```
############################################################
#   Default Logging Configuration File
#
# You can use a different file by specifying a filename
# with the java.util.logging.config.file system property.  
# For example java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile
############################################################

############################################################
#   Global properties
############################################################

# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes.  These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
##handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= ALL

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

# default file output is in user's home directory.
##java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = logjava.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
##java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
# INFO, FINER, FINEST, ALL
############################################################

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
org.smslib.level = ALL
#org.ajwcc.level = ALL
```

**ListPorts.bat**

```
set cp=./lib/myapp.jar;./lib/RXTXcomm.jar
set lib=./lib
java.exe -cp %cp%  -Djava.library.path=%lib%  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%lib%/logging.properties  com.myapp.ListPorts
pause
```

**src/com/myapp/ListPorts.java**

```
package com.myapp.ListPorts

//import javax.comm.*; // You my try using this, it might work as well
import gnu.io.*;  // RXTX com replacement
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class ListPorts {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // List portNames
        Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = ports.nextElement();
            String s = getPortInfo(portId);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // test open-close methods on each port
        ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();
            CommPort port = null;
            try {
                System.out.print("open " + portId.getName());
                port = portId.open(ListPorts.class.getName(), 2000);
                port.close();
                System.out.println("...closed");                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if (port != null)
                    try { port.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getPortInfo(CommPortIdentifier portid) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(portid.getName());
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append("portType: ");
        if (portid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            sb.append("serial");
        else if (portid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
            sb.append("parallel");
        else
            sb.append("unknown");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please accept answer, according to SO protocol, if it had any good use for your solution. If you found solution of your own let everyone know it. Post your own answer, describe solution and accept it.